# Avoid repitition of object initializers to create derived objects in Linq-to-Entities without using linq-to-objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

Is there a way to put an initializer in a function that can be translated to Linq-to-Entities without having to use Linq-to-objects/collections.

Example (This is what i want to do - but cannot do)

```
// SomeCollection = List<SomeObject>()
this.SomeCollection = db.SomeEntity.AsEnumerable()
       .Select(x => SomeObjectInitFunc(x));
```

`SomeObjectInitFunc` will look a bit like this

```
public static SomeObject SomeObjectInitFunc(SomeEntity se)
{
    return new SomeObject { SomeProp = se.SomeColumn };
}
```

The reason I want to do this is because I will need to create several of these `SomeObjects` from different pieces of code and would like to know if there is a way that I can avoid repeating myself.

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: You can return from a method a linq result using 'object' in the method definition : public static object SomeObjectInitFunc(SomeEntity se)